# Eclipse MouseFeed plugin equivalent for IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a Eclipse [MouseFeed](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mousefeed) plugin equivalent for IntelliJ IDEA?

I've found [Key promoter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1003) plugin for InteliJ but it was not updated since 2007 so I am afraid that this plugin can be incompatible with current IntelliJ editions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a fork of Key promoter](https://github.com/athiele/key-promoter-fork) available, which is apparently being actively developped. The readme file mentions compatibility with Intellij 2016.2, as well as a few additional functionalities. You have to download and install it manually, since it's not (yet?) available from Jetbrains's repository.

By the way, the original Key promoter was actually [last updated in 2012](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4455) - but for some reason, it appears as a different plugin in Jetbrains's repository after version 1.0.8.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. btw: do you know how to configure this plugin? I cannot find any configuration for this in IntelliJ :(

Comment: I tried installing version 2.0.7 of the fork, and I could find the settings in the Preferences screen, in the section Other Settings > Key Promoter.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new rewritten version of the original Key Promoter plugin called Key Promoter X. It can be installed directly from within IntelliJ.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9792-key-promoter-x

https://github.com/halirutan/IntelliJ-Key-Promoter-X